# Commons file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to upload a file from a jsp/ajax using apache commons file upload libs. Below is the code:

**JSP:**

```
function importFileListForm()  
{
var html = "<div><h3>Add File</h3></div>";
html += '<table style="margin-top:20px;" width="100%"><tbody>'; 
html += '<tr><td>Choose File</td><td><input id="fileId" type="file" name="fileName" required size="50"/></td><td></td></tr>';
html += '</tbody></table>';

$("#dialog-modal-content").html(html);
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 300,
      width: 600,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Submit": function() {
            importFileConfirm($("#fileId").val());
        }
      }
    }); 
});
}

function importFileConfirm(file)
{
var url = "/config/fileManageAction.do?method=importFile&file=" +file;
var req = new FormData();
req.append("f", file);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: req,
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {console.log(data);}

});
}
```

My method in action class:

```
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxSize);
      factory.setRepository(new File("/production/cpu/temp.xlsx"));

      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxSize );
      try{
          List fileItem = upload.parseRequest(request);
          java.lang.System.out.println("List  "+fileItem.size());

    //    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    //    java.lang.System.out.println("File Part "+filePart);

         // Process the uploaded file items
          Iterator i = fileItem.iterator();
          while(i.hasNext()){
              FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
              if(!fi.isFormField()){
                  java.lang.System.out.println("Fi "+fi);
                  String fieldname = fi.getFieldName();
                  java.lang.System.out.println("FieldName "+fieldname);
                  String filename =  FilenameUtils.getName(fi.getName());
                  java.lang.System.out.println("File Name "+fi.getString());
                  InputStream filecontent = fi.getInputStream();
              }else{
                  java.lang.System.out.println("not a form field");
                  java.lang.System.out.println("Fi "+fi);
                  String fileName = fi.getName();
                  java.lang.System.out.println("File Name: "+fileName);
              }


          }
      }catch(Exception e){
          java.lang.System.out.println("Exception occured "+e);
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

 //   }

 }
```

But in my file item i am only getting the field name and the `fi.getName()` is returning null. Can some one throw some light on what i am missing?.

I cannot use `getParts()` functions as my tomcat doesn't support it.

Comment: standard ajax doesn't allow for file uploads. the usual work around is to copy the file input's dom element into hidden iframe and doing a conventional upload from there.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for your response. Can you point me an example?.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the File object to the FormData object. `$("#fileId").val()` gives you the filename, to get the file use `$("#fileId")[0].files[0]`

```
req.append("f", $("#fileId")[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: If i do like this, i should use request.getParts() on my server side, correct?. But it seems my tomcat doesn't support this method.

Comment: I don't know jsp but it would be the same way if you was using a form to upload the file.